# Javascript not running on some IE 9 workstations

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have two different Windows 7 workstations that have the same exact version of IE 9.  One will run simple Javascript like the one below and the other will not.  All other settings appear to be the same - both are in compatibility mode accessing the page using SSL.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.location = "login.asp";
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `type="text/javascript"` attribute in your script tag? I believe `language="JavaScript"` is depreciated.

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript error console (press F12)? Do you see any  error (security related or otherwise)?

Comment: Both the "type" and "language" attributes are not really necessary.

Comment: add a noscript tag to see if javascript is executed at all